# Trying to paginate in asp.net server side getting 404

Tags: c#, angularjs, pagination, http-status-code-404, angular-resource

I'm trying to paginate server side, but when I run it's never hitting my api.

```
    [Route("{pageNumber:int}/{pageSize:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int pageSize, int pageNumber)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        List<AdminVM> admin = _adapter.GetAdminControl(pageSize, pageNumber);
        var totalcount = admin.Count();
        var totalPages = Math.Ceiling((double)totalcount / pageSize);
        var result = new
        {
            TotalCount = totalcount,
            totalPages = totalPages,
            Admin = admin
        };
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

This factory is making the call:

```
    (function () {
    angular
        .module('EnvisionApp')
        .factory('PaginationFactoryRouting', function ($resource) {
            return $resource("api/apiAdmin/:id",
                { id: "@ProjectID" },
                {
                    'query': {
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/api/clubs/:pageNumber/:pageSize',
                        params: { pageNumber: '@pageNumber', pageSize: '@pageSize'}
                    }
                });
        });
})();
```

any ideas?

Comment: What URL is being called? What is the `RoutePrefix` on the controller?

Comment: Thanks David. The router prefix was wrong. Silly me. If you want to give that as an answer I can say you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the URL for your controller is not correct. Check the [`RoutePrefix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on the controller to see what makes up the full URL. From the jQuery code you posted, add this to the controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("/api/clubs")]
public class ClubsController
{
    //snip
}
```